# tabbar. switching between uiviewcontroller with event

Tags: objective-c, uitabbar

I have tabbar application. There are 5 tabbar items with 5 uiviewcontrollers for each one. UIViewControllers are without xib files. I can switch between them, but i need to do some action on switching. Is there some event for this action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in all the view controllers, the following method will be called when you switch to that specific view controller.

```
 // inYourViewController.m file
 - (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
 {
    //insert your code here
    //EDIT
    [super viewWillAppear:YES];
 }
```

Comment: i don't see animation)
anyway, thanks, i received an answer:)